# Microsoft Graph - get admin details after consent

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having Microsoft app who asks for `User.ReadWrtie.All` permission through admin consent page.

After the admin of an organization gave his consent, he is being redirected to url I decide, and I get `tenant` value in request which I can use in order to acquire token and preform actions.

So far so good. Is there a way to get the admin details (first name, email, company name etc)?

I'm guessing that permission wise I have the permission to know this information, but in the docs ([get user documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0)) it seems like I must provide `userPrincipalName` (which I don't know) in order to get these details.

Is it possible to get the admin details some how? even if it means sending more than one request...

Comment: You are probably better off reading the users in the [global admin list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal).

Comment: wouldn't https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me just work for you, that should return the user details for the logged on user

Comment: @KalyanKrishna can you elaborate? it's unclear from the link you provided. Thanks

Comment: @GlenScales, /me doesn't work, I have no logged in user (giving consent on behalf of the organization != being logged in admin) so I get resourceNotFound when trying to do so. I just need the details of any admin, not necessarily the one gave the consent, if that make it easier...

Comment: @Noam , I was referring to using [Azure Mgmt REST Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) to [list the users in an Azure role](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the admin details some how?

We will not know the admin who gave the consent. You need to provide the userid/userPrincipalName to get the user details.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

Comment: What about getting the details of any admin of the organization? Is that possible?

Comment: @Noam Yes, you can. But you need Directory.Read.All role. You can call get directory role api to find admin role id and then list members. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing 'admin' role is the one with `displayName` `Company Administrator`. Thanks again.